# django development server mimetype issue - not handling css

Tags: python, css, django

Using python 3.3.5 and django 1.6.4 here.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

On the django development server (manage.py runserver) the above css file is getting served as text/plain and the styles are not loading.  Actually, all of my js files are getting served as text/plain as well, but it doesn't seem to matter for them.  text/plain was verified using the debugging tools in Chrome, but it's definitely not browser-specific as the styles are not loading in ff either.

I know the css is being loaded, since I get 200/304 status messages in the server console, so it's not a static file path type issue.

Initially when I ran mimetypes.guess_type('test.css') in the python console it gave me 'text/plain' as output.  I then ran mimetypes.add_type('text/css', '.css') and now mimetypes.guess_type('test.css') returns 'text/css'.  The server, however, still serves the files as text/plain.

Anyone have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django server uses `mimetypes` standard Python library to do that. It relates `.css` extension to `text/css`, but *first* it takes a look in system-wide storage of such relations.

- On Windows this is `HKCR\.css\Content Type` registry key.
- On Linux it's either `/etc/mime.types` or `~/.mime.types`.

Some bad-behaved software have added relation of `.css` to `text/plain` there.

Comment: More about change mimetype on Linux http://serverfault.com/questions/359667/css-files-are-reported-as-text-plain-by-mimetype-on-ubuntu-machine